Matrix optimization to minimize pruing satifying column constraints
Suppose we are given a matrix $A = [a_{i,j}]_{n\times m}$, where all entries are non-negative. In this matrix, we are allowed to exchange two elements, $a_{i,j}$ and $a_{i,j'}$, sitting in the same $i$-th row. We are to prune the minimum number of entries (thus making them 0), such that for a given positive constant $C$, the following holds for all columns $j$:
$$\sum_{i} a_{i,j} \le C$$
I have a greedy solution for this. First, we sort each rows. Now we observe the first column: if $\sum_{i} a_{i,1} \le C$, then the condition is automatically satisfied for all other columns. If that is not the case, then we exchange some elements in the first column with elements from other rows. The last column should have the most spare room. Thus, we can greedily pick one such row $i$ to make the exchange $a_{i,1} \leftrightarrow a_{i,m}$ such that we have a maximal gain in the constraint. If the constraint is still violated, we pick another row $i'$ to make a similar exchange. In this way, we get a satisfying column $1$. We delete this column from the matrix and repeat the same process for all columns. At the end, if a column is still violated, we again become greedy and prune bigger entries until the constraint is satisfied.
Now my question is twofold:

Is the problem NP-hard? If so, what could be a potential candidate for reduction?
If not, then can we do something better than the above greedy?


If I am not wrong, the above problem is indeed NP-hard. Consider a special case where we have only one column (thus no exchange is possible). Even in this restricted case, finding the maximum number of elements (or rows) such that the sum is below $C$ is non-trivial. Since this can be mapped to a SUBSET-SUM problem, which is a known NP-hard problem.

Please do correct me if I am wrong.
